# If input value between database value A and database value B, select database value A

Tags: php, database, range

I'm currently busy developing a price calculator based on prices in a database.

The customer specifies the needed width and height and the calculator should look-up the corresponding product and his price in the database.

Width = 10 & Height = 10: Price = 20

Width = 20 & Height = 10: Price = 30

**The problem I'm facing now:**

But if the width is in a range from 10 to 19, he should select the price where the width is 10. If the width is in a range from 20 to 29, he should select the price where the width is 20. Etc, etc.

**Current HTML input Form:**

```
<form action="Database-Output.php" method="post">

<table width="470" border="0">

  <tr>
    <td>Geef hier de door u gewenste hoogte in:</td>

    <td>
    <input type="number" name="height" width="100" placeholder="Hoogte">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Geef hier de door u gewenste breedte in:</td>

    <td>
    <input type="number" name="width" width="100" placeholder="Breedte">
    </td>
  </tr>

  </table>

<br />
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Bereken prijs">

</form>
```

**Current PHP form (Database-Output.php)**

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "addressbook";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = " . $_POST["height"] . "  AND width = " . $_POST["width"] . "";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['value'] . "<BR>";

}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

?>
```

**Database contains the following values:**

```
id
value (this is the price)
height
width
```

**An example of how the printed price table looks like**

http://www.entry-vouwgordijnen.nl/price_table.php

Is there any way to do this in an easy and simple to maintain way?

Thank you!

**ANSWER**

I used the following code to solve the problem:

```
$width = $_POST['width'];
    // Vaste variabele voor breedte
$height = $_POST['height'];
    // Vaste variabele voor hoogte

// ----------------------------TERUGREKENEN NAAR BENEDEN BREEDTE------------------------------ >> GOED //

if ($width % 10 == 0) { 

$widthrounded = $width;
    // If width ends with a zero, do not round the number

} else {

$widthrounded = ceil($width / 10) * 10 - 10;
    // If width does not ends with a zero, round down the number

}

// ----------------------------TERUGREKENEN NAAR BENEDEN HOOGTE------------------------------- >> GOED //

if ($height % 10 == 0) { 

$heightrounded = $height;
    // If height ends with a zero, do not round the number

} else {

$heightrounded = ceil($height / 10) * 10 - 10;
    // If height does not ends with a zero, round down the number

}

// ----------------------------IF DATABASE FOUND SELECT DB VALUE------------------------------ >> GOED //   

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = " . $heightrounded . "  AND width = " . $widthrounded . "";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

// ----------------------------PRINT RESULT AND CLOSE DB-------------------------------------- >> GOED //   

print $db_field['value'] . "<BR>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple function that will round up the number,

```
<?php
$width = $_POST['width'];

$width1 = $width - ($width % 10 - 10);

echo "The number ". $width ." rounded up is ". $width1 ."!"
?>
```

This function will round down,

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['width'];

$value1 = ceil($value / 10) * 10 - 10;

echo "The number ". $value ." rounded down is ". $value1 ."!"
?>
```

This function will check if width contains a zero, if it does it will pass variable, if it doesn't it will round down (the `strpos` checks for strings inside strings);

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['width'];

if (strpos($value,'0') !== false) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = " . $_POST["height"] . "  AND width = " . $value . "";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

}
else {
$value1 = ceil($value / 10) * 10 - 10;

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = " . $_POST["height"] . "  AND width = " . $value1 . "";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! The only problem I'm facing now is that the coding also rounds down rounded numbers. For instance 10 becomes 0 and 20 becomes 10. 10 should be 10 and 20 should be 20 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the meanwhile I figured out a similar way to fix this problem. Added it above!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of `if` statements should do it,

```
$height = $_POST["height"];
$width = $_POST["width"];

if ($width >= 10 && $width <= 19) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = '10'  AND width = '10' ";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
}

if ($width >= 20 && $width <= 29) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = '10'  AND width = '20' ";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
```

Comment: I thought if this one, but this is really going to give me a headache if you look at the amount of choices people can make.. Here is a link to a similar price table I use: http://www.entry-vouwgordijnen.nl/price_table.php